# Select all except those that match another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016: I want to query table1 and return all entries except where there's a match in table2's corresponding column.

I thought this would work:

```
select * 
from table1 
where table1.jobno not in(select jobno from dbo.table2)
```

But that returns no records. There are over 1000 records where table1.jobno is not in table2.  How to do this correctly?

Comment: Are those 1000 in the date range in your WHERE?

Comment: I think there is no data between those data range. What is happening when you remove the first condition and just leave the "not in" line.??

Comment: If I comment out the and table1... line, I get 19k records.

Comment: I think you should add some sample data to your question

Comment: If I remove the date restriction completely, the problem remains.

Comment: Not sure if it's the solution, but I recommend that you use ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD to ensure that your dates are interpreted correctly by SQL Server. So your where statement would be `between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'`

Comment: I've removed the date restriction completely.  Above and in my test code.  The problem remains.  The "select jobno from dbo.table2" seems to return true for any jobno.  I tried the opposite, removing the "not" and I get all records, whether or not they are in table2.  i.e.  `where table1.jobno in(select jobno from dbo.table2)`  also tried `where table1.jobno in(select table1.jobno from dbo.table2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` is dangerous to use with a subquery.  Why?  Because it returns *no* records if *any* of the values returned by the subquery are `NULL`.

For this reason, I strongly encourage you to use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.table2 t2 where t2.jobno = t1.jobno);
```

You can get the same effect using `left join`/`where not null` or by including a `where` clause in the subquery:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where t1.jobno not in (select t2.jobno from dbo.table2 t2 where t2.jobno is not null);
```

But I think that simply using `not exists` is simpler.

Comment: I'm a TSQL novice, can you elaborate on what this does?  `select 1`

Comment: @shorton . . . It selects the value "1".

Comment: He only need to check if `not exists` so if the query returns 1 ( or anything else) the conditions fails and the row isn't returned

Answer (score 1):

You make a left join and eliminate by looking only empty in Table2

```
SELECT
Table1.* 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.JobNo=Table2.JobNo
WHERE ISNULL(Table2.JobNo,'')=''
```

Another way

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE JobNo in (
    (
    SELECT JobNo from Table1
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT JobNo from Table2
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried a variant of the 1st thing that worked.  The second is new to me.  Works, and is more what I had in mind.  Fuzzy on why the original `where not In(select ...) ` does not work. :(